# How do we write the highest power of $n$ less than $x$?

Tags: notation

How do we write the highest power of $n$ which is less than or equal to $x$?

Obviously we can use $\max{\{n^m\mid n^m\leq x \land m\in\mathbb{N}\}}$

Or I guess we might say something like $$n^{\lfloor{\log_n{x}}\rfloor}$$

But surely there's something more compact than those?

I'm looking in particular for the value of the highest binary digit in some number.

Comment: Nah, I've thought about this before and $n^{\lfloor{\log_n{x}}\rfloor}$ is as good as it gets.

Comment: Declare a temporary compact notation for whatever you're writing.

Comment: @MarkS. wow that really is disappointing!

Comment: @OscarCunningham ^^